# jQuery Better Way to call function on multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, call

I'm wondering if there is a better way to handle multiple function calls. Basically I have a function which receives and element as one of the arguments, along with some properties. I have to call this function on several elements...

```
function positionMe(element,position){ ... }

positionMe(obj1,top);
positionMe(obj2,left);
positionMe(obj3,bottom);
positionMe(obj4,right);
positionMe(obj5,bottom);
```

Just looking at the code seems like I'm doing something really wrong. At first I thought I might be able to pass a collection of elements in, but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not pass all elements in an array at the same time and loop through it?

Comment: Would I just put the loop inside the function, or build an array of elements and place the loop where I'm calling the function? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the information you have provided I would create an array with all the needed information and loop through it inside your function:

```
function positionMe(elements)
{
    for(var i = 0, numberOfElements = elements.length; i < numberOfElements ; i++) {
        // Do stuff with the objects you want to do in here

        // access the current object
        console.log(elements[i].object);

        // access the current direction
        console.log(elements[i].direction);
    }
}

var yourObjects = [
    {
        object: obj1,
        direction: 'top'
    },
    {
        object: obj2,
        direction: 'left'
    },
    {
        object: obj3,
        direction: 'bottom'
    },
    // etc
];
positionMe(yourObjects);
```

**UPDATE**

As [Reflective commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593402/jquery-better-way-to-call-function-on-multiple-elements/12593521#comment16972852_12593521):

> better use for (var i in element) { console.log(elements[i].object);}

This is not the case for arrays in javascript. Well it's not that simple. because you will end up also looping through all the inherited stuff of the array object like e.g. `pop()`, `push()` etc. There is a way to prevent this though through [the use of `hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

Another way would have been to use [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) which is available as of JavaScript 1.6. So I don't think all user agents already builtin support for this.

Comment: better use `for (var i in element) { console.log(elements[i].object);}`

Comment: Actually no. You would also get other stuff (like inherited properties) than what you have defined. Unless you are using it in combination with `hasOwnProperty`. Why would it be better?

Comment: because `for (var i in elements) {...}` is doing the same as `for(var i = 0, numberOfElements = elements.length; i < numberOfElements ; i++) {...}` in more elegant way

Comment: No it is not doing the same thing. See my answer. tl;dr don't just use `for in` in javascript for arrays.

Comment: `var yourObjects = [ {
        object: {obj1:"aa"},
        direction: 'top'
},{
        object: "obj2",
        direction: 'left'
    },
    {
        object: "obj3",
        direction: 'bottom'
    },
    // etc
];

for (var i in yourObjects) { alert(i); }`    - just test it - the main thing you are missing is that we do not itearate an Object - we iterate an simple array ... if we iterate an Object we should check hasOwnProperty which actually is very useful ... for associative array the behaviour is the same ... check it yourself

Comment: And no worries. You cannot always be right. But JavaScript just works like this don't blame me :)

Comment: FF, IE, IE Comp mode, Chrome & Safari - returns 1,2,3 ... yes in the fiddle is different ... but ? better test in a real browser

Comment: I'm tired of this "discussion" and I'm going to leave it because I'm a nice guy. Good bye.

Comment: it seems you have tested it in a browser ... anyway

Comment: I thought for performance reasons you should avoid for in loops?

Comment: In theory it will perform worse, but I doubt you really are going to be hurt by this.

Comment: Would placing the loop inside the function be faster?

Comment: Not sure. Might be because you may loose some overhead of calling the function multiple times. But again you would not notice it. But imho it is cleaner to do it inside the function. However either way is fine with me.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script>

var objArray = [
 ["obj1","top"],
 ["obj2","bottom"],
 ["obj3","middle"]
];

$.each(objArray, function(i, v) {positionMe(v[0], v[1]);});

function positionMe(element, val) {
   alert (element+":"+val);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your objects are elements on the page, you can use jQuery's $.each() function to run the function on each event. The syntax would work like:

```
$('selector that grabs all objects').each(positionMe($(this), position));
```